# How to improve cooling in a room/Cool a concrete wall?

Tags: concrete, insulation, cooling

Im on a 2nd floor room, it has big front windows and a small one on the side, I am using my computer/full setup on the corner of the room, where beside me is the window wall, but since im in the corner, im surrounded by concrete walls, and it can get as hot as 36 celsius, maybe even more. In short, Im basically in a big concrete oven. I dont know what to do to cool down the whole room, moreso the concrete walls in my back and side. I already have an electric fan running to ventilate the whole room.

Comment: Thoroughly describe this room.  What doors, windows, heat and air return registers are present is relevant.  Concrete walls, or walls in general are not used to intentionally conduct heat away.

Comment: There is front wall with the big windows, it takes up about 1.5/2 of the wall, so in my corner side its just wall. There is a small window above me around 4 feet in length and 21" tall, and around 5 feet from the floor. The big windows are 5 feet long and the remaining wall is 4-5feet. 2 exterior walls are concrete around 8" thick and some 4" wood interior walls

Comment: Air vents?  How far can the windows be opened?

Comment: The small 4 feet window can only be opened halfway, the big ones are always fully opened. They're the only source of ventilation and fresh air aside from the door. More problems are, the windows so big it actually lets sunlight in too much and heats up the place more. We have wooden floors here and it sucks up heat too. Ceiling is fortunately insulated, but its still hot especially my back.

Comment: Mounting fans in the window and or putting your computer exhaust out the window would be worth thinking about.  You have to make the air that is hot not be in the room anymore and replace it with cool air.  If it's an option a mosquito net or awning outside the window can also help.

Comment: already got a big electric fan working, and im using a laptop cooling pad. Its still hot

Comment: A laptop cooling pad cools the laptop by putting the heat in the room.  if you had a desktop computer with the exhaust vented outside, even though it used more power it would put less heat in the room. Especially if a window has a screen on it you need a shrouded fan with decent static pressure, meaning the air has to go through the screen and can't flow back through other parts of the window.  Just putting a fan in front is not the same. You still haven't answered if there are any hot air or return vents.  If your house has a furnace the furnace can be used without the heater as a summer fan.

Comment: Gaming desktop is consume a lot of electricity which converts to heat. Do Sider you have a 700W heater.

Comment: Blocking the sunlight from coming in the windows can help a lot.  What type of outside air temperatures and humidity are you dealing with?  Have you thought about an air conditioner?

Comment: If you are allowed to modify your apartment and don't mind losing a small space, you can build a false wall filled with insulation material.